# Как подключить composer

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Я скопировал сайт с одного сервера на другой простым копированием (сайт на yii2). В проекте есть composer. И на новом сервере есть установленный глобально composer. Как подключить composer проекта чтобы он увидел все зависимости и можно было скачивать пакеты одной командой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да ничего не нужно подключать. Главное чтоб был файл composer.json и раз у вас уже действующий проект, то есть composer.lock. Просто заходите в директорию с composer.json и делаете `composer require yourPackage`. Тем более если у вас есть свой композер прям в проекте, то используйте его.